# automatic write back if user leaves page/system halts

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've been designing a site that is used to collect data, but the person I'm designing for wants some form of redundancy just in case the window is closed or the system shuts down. Is there any way to take data that's been collected and write it to a MYSQL database if the user is disconnected for a certain amount of time, or if they shut the browser window/shut the system down without submitting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done just with a pure HTML page - if the user doesn't submit the form, your server doesn't know what they've typed.

However, you could put some Javascript on the page that made an AJAX call every few seconds (or every few key-stokes or clicks). The idea would be for the JavaScript to invisibly submit the whole form to a PHP page which saved it into a sort of "holding area".

If the user then submitted the form, the holding area could be cleared out, but if they never did, then the data in the holding area would show you where they got to.

Answer (score 2):

The web is stateless and disconnected - so all data will (or rather: should be) persisted between page requests.

I assume you have a web-page generated by PHP that contains a lengthy data-entry form, and you want to save the data in that form in the event the user closes their browser window - the solution is to use a client-script that polls the server with the current data in the form, or at the very least hooks on to the window close event.

Actual implementation is a task left up to the OP.

Comment: Asking the user is much more polite (and, perhaps, _legal_) than sending the data to the server without their explicit action.  I like SO's little popup that appears when I'm about to abandon a comment.

Comment: @AlainCollins But you will also notice that SO auto-saves while you're typing an Answer, without your "consent".

Answer (score 1):

The most common techniques to partially prevent this szenario is that web apps work with a heartbeat-function which fires via javascript in a constant interval and sends a request to the server, p.e. to show that the user is still logged on - or, in your case, maybe to submit data already typed into form fields, too.

Think of it as an ajax-powered auto-save-function!

You have to add some javascript to your code for this, but the commonly used javascript libraries, like jquery or mootools, are well documented and offer alot of examples how to do something like this.

Comment: If you are auto-saving, make sure you're not assuming that the user has completed the entire flow of your site.  On many systems, the terms&conditions checkbox is on the last page, but if the user hasn't agreed yet, you better not be using their data!

Comment: Of course. The techniques involved should be adapted properly to the desired solution.

Comment: @AlainCollins To extend the "auto-save" comparison, an editor or word-processor will not normally overwrite the "real" file being edited when it autosaves, instead putting it in a "private" store to be retrieved if necessary.

Comment: @IMSoP Absolutely.  I didn't mean to say it was hard, just that it all should be considered.  Thanks for the example, which might help them design a solution.